# generating characters depending on input number

Tags: c++

```
// direction generator
static const char alpha[] = "DLP";
int d;
char genRandom()
{
    return alpha[rand() % d +1];
}
// end of generator 

while(true)
{
    cout << genRandom();
}
```

It should generate `d` characters. Example:

input d:

```
7
```

output of random generator:

```
PDLDPLP
```

And Im getting unlimited number of strings, program doesnt stop at 7. It keeps going forever.

Comment: When did you imbue `d` with a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It runs forever because you use `while(true)`.

You can use a counter instead, which stops when reaching the number you need.

```
for (int counter=0; counter<d; counter++)
{
    cout << genRandom();
}
```

---

**Edit:** And you need to fix your `genRandom()` which will get out-of-range error when `d>2`.

Try to change

```
return alpha[rand() % d +1];
```

to

```
return alpha[rand() % strlen(alpha)];
```

Answer (score 0):

As herohuyongtao said, you're using `while(true)`.

Try something like this instead:

```
char GetRandomChar(){
    char differentCharacters[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
    int numOfCharacters = 3;
    return differentCharacters[rand() % numOfCharacters ];
}

int main(){
    int n;
    int numChars = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    while(numChars++ < n){
        std::cout << GetRandomChar();
    }
}
```